# Install only modules with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have some modules i want to deploy with setuptools.

i wrote this short setup.py:

```
from ez_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mystuff',
      version='1.0',
      description='some lib',
      url='https://...',
      install_requires=['pymssql'],
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      packages=[''],
      )
```

but i get this Warning:

```
WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
```

The modules get correctly deployed but is there a clean way to do this? If the packages line is removed, no modules are copied.

Comment: Why not use `py_modules` instead then?

Comment: i read the documentation and it writes that you should use this, when you not want to explicitly add every single module

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [Python package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package), you can specify it in [the `packages` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages).

As you describe it, though, you do not have Python packages; you have only modules.

If you want to install Python modules that are *not* packages, you instead use [the `py_modules` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules).